# how to listener the addView operate?

Tags: android

i add a view in the xml,like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#000000"
              android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

now ,i want to replace Button's viewParent,but how do i know when the LinearLayout add the Button child in the custom Button?

Of course, it must listener before the onCreate method.